# Obtaining List of Coordinates for Route Along Nearest Edge Using OSMnx, Python and Leaflet

Tags: python, routes, leaflet, openstreetmap, osmnx

I am currently working on a mapping project using Leaflet, where I need to obtain a list of coordinates representing a route between an origin marker and a destination marker. Specifically, I want the route to start along the edge closest to the starting or finishing coordinates, and then follow the exact path of the route.

Here's what I've done so far:

- I successfully obtained coordinates for both the origin and destination markers using Leaflet.
- I used functions like `nearest_edges` and `nearest_nodes` to find the closest edge and node for both the origin and destination coordinates.
- I developed logic based on the direction of the edge and whether the node is on the edge.
- I used the `interpolate_points` function to divide the starting and finishing edge using its linestring and calculate the distance to the origin/destination coordinate to determine the starting point.
- From there, I generated a list of coordinates from the point on the edge to the nearest node for both the origin and destination.
- To complete the route, I obtained the route using `shortest_path` and retrieved the linestring for every edge in it. Then, I inserted these linestrings between the starting and finishing segments to generate a complete list of coordinates.

However, I believe there might be a more efficient or straightforward approach to accomplish this task. I'm particularly interested in methods that allow me to obtain a list of coordinates for a route that can start in the middle of an edge.

Any insights, suggestions, or alternative methods would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Edit:
Here is a link to a simplified version of my [code](https://github.com/Vestigialmars5/TMS-Project/blob/master/tests/simplified.py).

Comment: Please provide a complete, minimal, reproducible code snippet for us to reproduce and troubleshoot.

Comment: Also note that OSMnx builds graph models of the street network. A graph is a set of nodes linked to each other by a set of edges. There is no concept of a path along a graph starting in the middle of an edge: by definition, paths are between nodes. Thus, any such project would require some ad hoc geospatial work, as you noted.

Comment: @gboeing Apologies in advance, I added a link to a file in my repository. I have tried reducing the code as much as possible. This is also my first time sharing code or asking a question, so it might be very noisy code. If you have any questions or comments, please let me know. Any type of feedback will be very appreciated.